# Using Ansible GKE modules for modifying gke cluster parameters

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ansible, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine

We are using the below `Ansible` modules to build our `GKE` clusters.

```
      google.cloud.gcp_container_cluster
      google.cloud.gcp_container_node_pool
```

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/google/cloud/gcp_container_node_pool_module.html

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/google/cloud/gcp_container_cluster_module.html

The following is the code snippet

```
   - name: create a cluster
     google.cloud.gcp_container_cluster:
         name: cluster-nodepool
         initial_node_count: 4
         location: us-central1-a
         project: "{{ gcp_project }}"
         auth_kind: "{{ gcp_cred_kind }}"
         service_account_file: "{{ gcp_cred_file }}"
         state: present
         register: cluster

      - name: create a node pool
        google.cloud.gcp_container_node_pool:
            name: my-pool
            initial_node_count: 4
            cluster: "{{ cluster }}"
            location: us-central1-a
            project: test_project
            auth_kind: serviceaccount
            service_account_file: "/tmp/auth.pem"
            state: present
```

Cluster creation and deletion is working fine for us, but we are struggling with modification of existing `gke` parameters. For example use cases like

```
   1) Changing the initial no of Nodes in Cluster
          initial_node_count: 6
   2) Adding more network tags 
   3) Add more entries to authorized networks  etc
```

Such use cases of modifying existing `gke` parameters is not taking place using `ansible`. We have to make changes these changes using the GKE console only.

Can we modify parameters of any `GCP` resource created using `Ansible` or `Ansible` is for one time infrastructure creation only and subsequent changes has to be from `GCP` console.

Or is it something like the `Ansible GKE` modules we are using does not support modifying/adding parameters for existing `GKE` Clusters